# How to remove an item from list without using the remove() method?

Tags: c#, list, methods

I want to remove the last item from the list but it's not allowed to use methods. Any ideas?

<I don't want to rewrite my whole code so here we are... xd>

```
 Keres.Remove(Keres[Keres.Count - 1]);
```

this also doesn't seem to help me

```
 Keres[Keres.Count - 1] = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compose a new list with every item but the last:

```
var temp = new List< {Whatever type is used for Keres} >();
for(int i = 0; i < Keres.Length - 2; i++)
{
    temp.Add(Keres[i]);
}
Keres = temp;
```

This never calls a method on the `Keres` variable (unless you understand both index access and properties (`.Length`) are implemented as method calls behind the scenes).

But **don't do this**. Not being able to use the Remove() or RemoveAt() method is stupid, and there's no other reasonable way.

Comment: +1 on stupid. The only reason to have a constraint like that is if you are creating an immutable list: but for that you'd use a Lisp-style CAR-CDR list